# GHC option for performance related files out directory

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I made instrumental build which generates profiling information. I use `stack`. GHC options in `.cabal` file are:

```
ghc-options:     -Wall
                 -O2
                 -threaded
                 -prof
                 -fprof-auto
                 -rtsopts
                 -fprof-cafs
                 "-with-rtsopts=-N -s -h -i0.1 -p -M1G -SMyApplication-S.log"
```

so running application generates files: `MyApplication-S.log, MyApplication.hp, MyApplication.prof`, but in current working directory - which is the problem, sure (also I need to run it on Windows and Linux). Is it possible to specify directory of those output files with some option? Because, without it I will get "Can't open ... file..." error due to permission error - Haskell Runtime tries to save all of them in current folder (on Linux and on Windows standard folders for binaries are not allowed for writing).

Answer (score 0):

After reading of GHC source code (Profiling.c and RtsFlags.c) I found that it's possible with `-po` option:

```
ghc-options:     -Wall
                 -O2
                 -threaded
                 -prof
                 -fprof-auto
                 -rtsopts
                 -fprof-cafs
                 "-with-rtsopts=-N -s -h -i0.1 -p -po/My/Dir/MyApplication -M1G -S/My/Dir/MyApplication-S.log"
```

So, will be created same 3 files but now in `/My/Dir` folder.